# Alexa prompt when user disables a custom skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My custom skill has account linking which works fine, but in the mobile Alexa app when the user clicks disable skill, most of the skill in Alexa shows a popup saying "If you disable , any skill-related information will be deleted. Would you like to disable the skill?"

My custom skill is not saying this. How do I configure this?